# Using a static variable to create a unique code with each instance of the object

Tags: java

I am trying to create a unique property code every time I create new instance of the House class. For example, when I create the third house in my program, I need it to assign the integer '3' to it so that I can reference the house with that unique code. I have attempted this with a global static variable and while retaining the correct amount of objects created, it only ever returns the last instance's value.

```
private static int houseNo = 0;
private int propertyCode;

public House(String s, Town t, Person o){
    owner = o;
    street = s;
    town = t;
    houseNo++;
    propertyCode = houseNo;
}
public String toString(){
    String temp = "";
    temp = "Code: " + this.getPropCode() + " \nAddress:\n" + this.getStreet() + ", " + town.getTownName();
    return temp;
}
```

Say I have created 6 houses in my main class, using the toString to access any house will only return 6 in place of the getPropCode().

Any ideas?

Edit(More code):

```
public int getPropCode(){
    return propertyCode;
}
```

And from my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   House house1 = new House("blueberry", town1, fred);
   House house2 = new House("blackberry", town2, barney);
   House house3 = new House("redberry", town3, fred);
   int whichHouse = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select a house to create a lease for \n1. " + house1.toString() + "\n2. " + house2.toString() + "\n3. " + house3.toString()));
```

Please forgive my naming convention, just trying to mess around with this code.

Comment: I bet you that's because your `getPropCode()` is implemented as `int getPropCode(){return houseNo;}` :):):):)

Comment: Can you post more code? Perhaps the `getPropCode()` method, as well as the code creating your `House` objects, and the code that's calling the `toString()` method on all your `House` objects. While it's probably not a good idea to maintain a `static int` as a reference to how many houses you've created, your `propertyCode` instance variable (since it's NOT static) should be incrementing properly.

Comment: Sure thing. Will add those in...

Comment: Do you want to maintain a count of the number of House objects instantiated or do you want to associate unique identifier with each object instance?

Comment: I was attempting to do both at once, using the count of objects instantiated as the indentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you expecting like this, updated attribute for simplicity

```
public class Test {     
    private static int count = 0;

    public static void main( String [] args) { 
        House h1 = new House("blueberry", "town1", "fred");
        System.out.println(h1.toString());
        House h2 = new House("blackberry", "town2", "barney");
        System.out.println(h2.toString());
        House h3 =new House("redberry", "town3", "john");;
        System.out.println(h3.toString());              
    } 
}

class House {
    String name;
    String person;
    String town;
    private int propertyCode;
    static int count = 0;

    public House(String name,String town,String person){
        count = count +1;
        this.propertyCode = count;
        this.town = town;
        this.person = person;
        this.name = name;

    }
    public String toString(){
        String temp = "";
        temp = "Code: " + this.name + " " + this.propertyCode;
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: This did it. It was as simple as adding a "this." statement to my incrementation. Thanks upog

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, this code is not thread-safe, and there will be a race condition if multiple threads call the constructor at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not thread safe, so you should consider using AtomicInteger

```
private static AtomicInteger houseNo = new AtomicInteger(0);

public House(String s, Town t, Person o){
    owner  = o;
    street = s;
    town   = t;
    propertyCode = houseNo.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Specifically, it's these two lines where multiple threads running through the constructor could give you unexpected results

```
...
houseNo++;
propertyCode = houseNo;
...
```

Of course, AtomicInteger will only supply unique propertyCodes within a single JVM, but maybe that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, so check again your code, and specially your "getPropCode"

```
public class House{

    private static int houseNo = 0;
    private int propertyCode;

    public House(){
        houseNo++;
        propertyCode = houseNo;
    }

    public int getPropCode(){
        return propertyCode;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "code: "+getPropCode();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        House a = new House();
        House b = new House();
        House c = new House();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);

    }

}
```